# How should I add multiple markers using geofield module?

Tags: google-maps

Whenever I set the module with unlimited values there are more the one maps with location. However they show the location which I want, but in two or more different maps.

My problem is I want to integrate multiple location with a single map. My project is kind of setting the route for people.

How do I do that? Should I create a hook for the [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) module?

Comment: Merci for the accept (+ upvote). Next question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](https://www.drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it (it would be way too long to include a quote of it all here). That project page also includes various screenshots.

**Note**: Uploading custom markers should be possible also, similar to what you can see in the [screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/custom%20markers.jpg) in the feature request about [Custom markers](https://www.drupal.org/node/1985952).

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7 ...

Comment: My reputation is below 15 so i cant even cast vote for your answer. however i can say its was helpful. and thanks for sharing.

Comment: Done Sir.. Thank you for your time .... Can i ask one more question?? It is really important for me... As i m new to drupal i am facing a little problem in integrating maps with Entityform..Actually i have to add multiple locations in of form of a route and show it after the submit button in a single map...  how do i do that??? i am using drupal 7 in this case.... thanks

Comment: @AnirbanNeogi : no need for "sir" (just Pierre is fine). I suggest you post that new question in your previous comment as a NEW question. That way it allows anybody to post an actual answer (instead of trying to squeeze it in a few comments or so). OK? PS: now that "this" question is answered, and according to the rules of this site, it is not allowed to "change" the question here anymore (or add a new question to it). Just to avoid that it would invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Okay @Pierre.Vriens